# Can I take a flight from Frankfurt to India on the expiry day of my polish temporary residence card?

Tags: poland, long-stay-visas, frankfurt

My Polish temporary residence card expires on 29th of this month and I have a flight from Frankfurt on 29th evening, will there be any objections raised at the airport??

Comment: If you leave before midnight, you will be fine.

Comment: I have a flight that is scheduled at 21:30, that means I shouldn't have any problem. Did I get it right??

Comment: Yes, 21:30 is before midnight!

Answer (score 3):

Your residence card is valid till the midnight of the day. As long as you clear immigration before then, you are fine.